# Data Retrieving issue Node

Tags: node.js

I linked the picture of my folder, and the error Im getting.

I have two files app.js and index.js.

app.js takes data from index.js, however when I try to retrieve that data by using "node app.js" I get the errors.

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye6o0.png

Comment: looks like you're trying to require flight.js, which I don't see you have. do you? did you mean to require index instead? I'm talking about the first line in app.js

Comment: @NirLevy I have changed it to require('./index'). and I get nothing when I type node index.js

Comment: You need to paste in your actual code, not a screen shot.

Comment: @jfriend00 Screenshot is fine? Lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your module is named `index.js`, not `flight.js`. So try `require('.')`/`require('./')` or `require('./index')`.